# Send Order Email Programmatically Magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-email

How To **send Order Email** `Programmatically` In **Magento 2.2.8**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
    $email = 'example@example.com';

    $orderid = 100;

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderid);

    $order->setCustomerEmail($email);
    if ($order) {
        try {
            $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderNotifier')->notify($order);
            echo 'You sent the order email.';
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            echo($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo(__('We can\'t send the email order right now.'));
            echo($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should avoid using object manager like this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html#usage-rules

Comment: Thank you.. : )

Comment: @RkRathod Please do up vote and accept the answer so it will helpful for other developers.

Comment: approve answer on jul 8

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```php
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;



{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;
    /**
     * @var OrderSender
     */
    private $orderSender;
    /**
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param OrderSender $orderSender
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        OrderSender $orderSender
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
    }
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function doStuff()
    {
        // load order however you would like
        $order = [load order logic]
        try {
            $this->orderSender->send($order);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+ for response